# Large file upload not going to custom error page when way over size limit

Tags: c#, iis, file-upload, web-config, timeout

In my web config I specify a max size allowed and the custom error page with the following settings:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="600"/>
.
.
.
</system.web>


<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <clear/>
        <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" path="/Site/Error" responseMode="Redirect"  />
        </httpErrors>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I think the issue might be related to a timeout. In my dev environment, I get redirected to the error page regardless of how large the file is. In QA (not a local server), the page gets to about 80-90% uploaded and then I get sent to this generic page:

[image]

If I use a file that is just marginally over the limit, it properly sends me to the error page.

I assume what is happening is that in dev, it "uploads" very quickly, determines it is too large and then sends me to the proper page. But in QA it cuts off the connection before that point due to some timeout setting. But, I have a good `executionTimeout` value. Is there maybe a `<system.webserver>` sub-setting I am missing? Or maybe there is some IIS setting I need to make on QA?

If the answer to both of those is no, anyone know what else I should look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is an additional setting in IIS for timeouts. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits

I got to this from this pretty solid answer on SO:
[How to set different Timeouts for different URLs in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379259/how-to-set-different-timeouts-for-different-urls-in-asp-net)