# IIS connection timeout and connection string timeout attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm confused in those two terms I want to know what is the difference between the timeout inside the connection string and the timeout inside the IIS configuration

```
data source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=Test;User=yy;Password=yyyy;Timeout=10
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB connection timeout is very diffrent from IIS time out

DB connection timeout is about establis the connection to DB, from [MSDN SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Gets the time to wait while trying to establish a connection before
>   terminating the attempt and generating an error.

From [MSDN about Connection Timeout](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/31a2f39c-4d59-4cba-905c-60e7af657e49.mspx?mfr=true)

> Connection timeouts help reduce the amount of memory resources that
>   are consumed by idle connections. Time-out settings also allow you to
>   specify how long server resources are allocated to specific tasks or
>   clients.

Comment: if i reduced the Connection time out to 10 sec for example what kind of error or problems may accrue ?

Comment: reduce it in DB or IIS ? if DB than if your DB will not response quickly then you will get an error. If IIS  then is connection will be idle for the connection timeout period the resources will be free

Comment: I meant in IIS not in DB and is there an example where can i throw that error and see how it work ? in my scenario i have a page where i can upload a huge excel file notice huge mean it contains more than 15 000 row and sometime in the upload process it throws that kind of error so we r confused if we should maximize the timeout in connection string or the IIS timeout

Comment: Increase the DB timeout - since the IIS connection is not Idle. But, are you trying to save all rows at once?

Comment: we had that other problem that we read the excel file and convert it to a DataTable than we use a Stored Procedure to insert those row in the DB but it's too slow i can't change the Stored Procedure code so do u have a best solution for that ?

Comment: You can use bulk insert - did you try it ? or insert 1000 rows at a time. Need to understand more in order to give better option. if you insert large amount of data , you can lock the table and cause other user query to fail.

Comment: i can't change the stored procedure content so i can't use bulk insert but i read about SQLBulkCopy class but it turned out i can't use it with stored Procedure .. one more question can i set the IIS connection time out just for one page not for the whole website ?

Comment: if the SP take long time try to split the rows. not a master at IIS configuration , maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379259/how-to-set-different-timeouts-for-different-urls-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

The timeout in the database connection string is the amount of time ADO.NET should spend trying to connect to a database server before deciding it is unavailable (which is unrelated to the *command* timeout, note). `Connect` in a database connection string is a synonym for `Connect Timeout`.

The timeout in IIS is how long it should spend trying to process a request before deciding that it has failed.

Comment: so if for example i am uploading a large file to the server and that file took more time than the IIS connection time out would it give me an error ?