# Custom Configuration Settings for Specific ASP.NET MVC4 URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering whether it is possible to define `web.config` settings specifically for certain URLs.

For example:
Let's say I have an MVC4 web site with a bunch of controllers and actions, one of which allows uploading a large file (max. 50MB). By default, the `maxRequestLength` is 4MB. In `web.config` one would then add the following rule:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
```

However, this means that the request length is now 50MB for every action on the website.
Is it possible to make custom settings for specific URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `location` for setting different values. See this answer for instance [How to set different Timeouts for different URLs in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379259/how-to-set-different-timeouts-for-different-urls-in-asp-net) It's for setting a timeout, but it's the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set it in controller itself using [MaxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx) property, but not sure if it is possible to set it for specific action. Approach with `location` setting will not work, because MVC uses routing.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to create a new folder and place your controllers that you need and create a web.config for that folder.
And i think this is not a good approach :)