# Default Limits <limits> for IIS Express

Tags: iis-express

I need to test a file upload component that will be accepting very large files. I want to test locally in my development environment but since I use IIS Express instead of IIS 7 I am not sure where to make the global change.

In IIS 7 the change cannot be made via the web.config but needs to be changed through the IIS Manager Tool. See [this IIS article](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits) for an example.

Does anyone know how to make the same global change using IIS Express (in Visual Studio 2013)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If [the web.config change ppascualv suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28411264/70345) doesn't work, try putting it in the IIS Express **applicationhost.config**, which can be found at

```
%userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

under

```
<system.webServer>
```

put

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

This should set it as a global, unless a web.config from an application overrides it.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out this for one for a whole day.. [DisableRequestSizeLimit] or any other recommendations I could find did not work, but this worked all right. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You basically need to set both in *web.config*  `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` to upload files.

- `maxRequestLength` **Indicates the maximum file upload size supported by ASP.NET**
- `maxAllowedContentLength` **This specifies the maximum length of content in a request supported by IIS**.

***Note:`maxRequestLength` is in kilobytes & `maxAllowedContentLength` is in Bytes***

*By default, Machine.config is configured to accept HTTP Requests upto 4096 KB (4 MB) and it is reflected in all your ASP.NET applications. You can change the Machine.config file directly, or you can change only the Web.config file of the application(s) you want to*

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

---

```
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Your answer mentions maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength but your examples show 2 instances of maxAllowedContentLength and no example of maxRequestLength

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned already you need to modify `applicationhost.config` and put into it

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

What other people didn't mention is that when you are running your web app from Visual Studio, the location of `applicationhost.config` in the root directory of your project is
`.vs\{your_project_name}\config\applicationhost.config` and this is the file you will need to modify

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: The instructions I read said specifically that this setting could not be made in the web.conf but had to be set via the IIS Manager app. Here is the original SO article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379259/how-to-set-different-timeouts-for-different-urls-in-asp-net

Comment: This setting can be changed in web.config, did you try it? If you are moving your app between environments you are probably better off using web.config anyway over trying to do it in the GUI on each server / environment since the settings your app requires are then always copied to the environment you are deploying to?

Comment: I think all that you can do in IIS Manager can be done in web.config, however, IIS configuration can overwrite web.config. I didn't try this specific code, by I tryed with another inside <security>

Comment: The web.config change may work for IIS Express even if it doesn't for IIS 7

Comment: Just make sure that <system.webServer> is only nested within <configuration> tag of web.config and no other tags.

Answer (score 2):

Working to get around the "400 Bad Request" due to request headers that are too big, against the Visual Studio 2019's default IIS Express instance, I couldn't get Sarah's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437720/5853218) to work, but found that the http.sys settings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/httpsys-registry-windows) did the trick.

Specifically, I created inside `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` a DWORD registry value called `MaxRequestBytes` and setting it to a large enough value. For me, `33000` was enough. Also created `MaxFieldLength` in the same place, and set it to `33000`. A machine reboot is mandatory for the setting to become effective.

As for the cause of my problem, it's described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11997). It's essentially caused by authentication cookies that get placed inside the request headers. Pushing to an Azure App Service works just fine (the limit for the headers there is probably 32KB), but against the local IIS Express, it failed continuously, until the fix described above.

Comment: Changing webConfigs didn't solve the problem, creating registry keys worked! I also used Visual Studio 2019' IIS Express