# ASP.NET Core 6 File too large (413) with IIsExpress Profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to upload a file with a size of round about 80Mb to my controller:

```
[HttpPost("UploadJar")]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 104857600)]
public ActionResult UploadJar([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
            if (file is not { Length: > 0 })
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var filePath = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}{Guid.NewGuid()}.jar";

            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
            {
                file.CopyTo(stream);
            }

            if (ValidateJarFile(filePath) == false)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                return BadRequest();
            }

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("jarFileTempPath", filePath);
            return Ok();
}
```

My `Startup` class contains the following configuration:

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MaxRequestBodySize = 120000000; // 120Mb
    });
    
services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 120000000; // 120Mb, if don't set default value is: 30 MB
    });
```

And the profiles I use with Jetbrains Rider are:

```
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ASP.NETCoreWebApplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

When I use the profile `ASP.NETCoreWebApplication` everything is fine, but if I use the profile `IIS Express`, I get a 413 (file too large) error when uploading a file.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In web. config under System.WebServer you need to put this. Or if you are using rider then use that in the Rider application host file.

```
<security>
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
</requestFiltering>
</security>
```

see the following link - [Default Limits <limits> for IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155342/default-limits-limits-for-iis-express)

Comment: Ok but Jetbrains Rider has its own applicationhost.config file. It is under %PROJECT_ROOT%\.idea\config

Comment: I think there you can find the security tag and do the same.