# Applying location element in Web.config to a single file or API endpoint

Tags: .net, iis, web-config

I have a `Web.config` file in my .NET Framework app hosted on IIS. Inside the `Web.config`, I have a `location` element like so:

```
...
<location path="Controllers/api">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="secrectMessage" value="myAwesomeValue"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
...
```

`secretMessage` is just for testing, what I really want is the timeout.
My goal is to have the `executionTimeout` apply to only one API controller file, or even just one endpoint if possible. (I could split out that endpoint to its own file if files are as specific as `Web.config` will go.) Using the structure above, when I go to IIS Manager and navigate to the `Controllers/api` folder, and click Application Settings, I am able to see the `secretMessage/myAwesomeValue`. Does this mean that the `executionTimeout` is also set at this directory? I don't see any confirmation of that in the Manager UI.

When I change the `path` value to `"Controllers/api/MyController.cs"` I can't confirm the setting in the Manager UI because I can only navigate to directories. (It seems like every example of `<location>` has an `.aspx` file. Is there a reason for this?) Would changing the path to include the `.cs` file work to change the settings on calls made to this controller? Is there a way to specify `Web.config` settings for just one endpoint inside the controller?

**Edit:** I came up with another idea, which is to break the controller into two `partial class` files, one inside an addition directory `Controllers/api/extendedTimeout` to be able to apply the config to that directory. This seems to have done the same thing as far as I can tell in IIS Manager. Though, in the C# in `Controllers/api/extendedTimeout/MyControllerExtension.cs`, I have `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secrectMessage"];' but this returns null.

Comment: ExecutionTimeout apply to only one API controller file. If you want to implement something like set different Timeouts for every URLs. Here is a similar program: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6588864/20058276.

Comment: "I don't see any confirmation of that in the Manager UI." In the IIS manager, the setting you can see is the connection timeout in the advanced settings, and you can also find it in the web.config in the root directory of IIS. ConnectionTimeout, specifies the time (in seconds) that IIS waits before it disconnects a connection that is considered inactive. ExecutionTimeout, specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET.